# how should I write my about me in my website personal if I am a software developer junior

Tags: portfolio

Hello everyone I am come back this question is about my website and my section about me :

look I wrote this:

> Hi everyone , welcome to my website where you can see my amazing last project , I LOVE ALL about programming is that you can make everything you want to make with some language programming, I dont make simples solutions, I love making innovation in every project that I work, I love make friendship with every team work too and share own tips and advice as Software Developers, I love get into in every challenge I can do and work and righr now I am getting new skills everyday for improve in this world.

what do you think put in my "about me"? it is right or should I put other information like my experiencie or last project?

[image: website]

what should I write?

for example I got some ideas  of what I should write, for example:

1. About my dream
2. About my soul
3. About my experience in my last project and how i fixed.

   so I think there should put in other section like my experiencie or other place, what do you think?

Comment: You might want to consider taking a writing course first

Comment: some recomendation?

Comment: I am not expert in this topics for this reason I ask for get advice of a expert

Comment: Local language centers? Your university if you went to one?

Comment: sorry i am try improve my english everyday

Comment: No need to apologize. Language is difficult. Nobody is perfect. Nobody can even agree what perfect is, as language is constantly changing as the world changes around us. Keep working at it and you will keep getting better.

Comment: Here are some grammar checkers that come with correction suggestions: [Nounplus](https://www.nounplus.net/grammarcheck) and [Ginger](https://www.gingersoftware.com/grammarcheck)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might need to clarify what the intention behind creating this website is. Taking the place where you posted this and the fact that you link your CV I'm assuming you want to make some sort of online-portfolio, showcasing your skills as developer for potential employers. In case wanted to start a blog, because that's more of what your writing style reads like, I will leave the answering to that for someone else.

First off, as harsh as it may sound, I'd recommend to overthink wether you are actually in need of writing the whole stuff in english, rather than your native language, which I again assume is not english. Portfolio's and CV's written in english are mostly of interest for companies using the same language for their daily business. Reading your whole text I came to the conclusion that you're probably not fit for daily business talks in english and most HR-departments will likely conclude the same.

It makes no sense to advertise your skills to a company you are not fit to work with because of obstacles like language. Therefore, I'd rather recommend you to re-write the whole thing in a language you are more comfortable with and apply to companies using the same language as their business language.

In case you actually intend to apply to an english-speaking company, take a course teaching you the necessary speaking and writing skills first.

But as this was not actually the core point of your questions, let's skip to what you really asked.

## **What do you think "About Me"?**

To be honest your text is rather poorly written. Try to avoid repeating words and choose a more business-like style of describing yourself. E. g. instead of "I LOVE ALL about programming [...]" you could start your sentence with "I am very passionate about my work as a programmer [...]", which already sounds way more professional. Also **never** write in capslock when in a professional field.

Furthermore, one get's the impression that you are treating the reader like some kind of "buddy", which is not true. The HR-department is not your buddy, especially not when you are applying to them. Avoid phrases like "Hi everyone, welcome [...]" or "No[?] Do not worry [...]". Leaving this impression could made be unintentional by you because of lacking writing skills, but you should definitely change it anyway.

The Rest is mostly bad grammar and some over-the-top positive phrases.

## **What should I write?**

**About my dream**
Possibly, but keep it short. Make it more of what you envision for your future career.

**About my soul**
No. This is not a blog-post and you are desiring to get a job as a developer, not for some esotheric stuff.

**About my experience in my last project and how I fixed it**
Yes! That's probably something the person potentially interviewing you would be most interested in, but make sure you still keep something you can tell in a F2F interview later on.